# Rectangular box with rounded corners around text within a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to get the box around Sign Up smaller, ideally, halfway between the text and current state.

[image: Navigation Bar image link]

.  I am using bootstrap-3. I tried making the btn smaller (btn-sm), it seamed like that is the problem. But that doesn't do anything.
Here is what I have:

```css
.btn {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
    font-size: 18px;
}
#signup {
    border-color: #fff;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------
Navigation bar
-------------------------------------------------*/
.navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
}
.navbar { 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MyWebsite</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" >
                <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
                  
                  <!-- I'm trying to get the text in the button below within a rectangle box -->
                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse" id="signup">Sign up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

Answer (score 0):

There is padding/margin  between the button and the text, you need to look up at CSS file. There is two CSS files for bootstrap.

Find `btn-sm` in both CSS files. It will be inside one of them. However I see that you also have `btn btn-inverse` for button class. Do look at them.

If you want the corners of button to be more cursive, find the `border-radius` property.